# No route matches [GET] error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

new to rails (and programming) here. I am having an error in my app when uploading a photo, in which the broken photo icon appears and the image is set to "/images/medium/missing.png"

I have ImageMagick and Paperclip set up, migrations done, everything seems to be in order, no errors except for this. And it does not actually give an error, the upload seems to go through but it just shows the broken photo icon.

Here is my routes.rb:

```
  MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins

  devise_for :users
  root "pages#home"

  get "about" => "pages#about"
  get "team" => "pages#team"
```

not sure what else might help to provide just let me know.

User Model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

```
has_many :pins
```

end

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? What is the URL you are trying to access? What are you doing in the view to display the image?

Comment: What is in your `log/development.log` file?

Comment: do you have the folder medium containing missing.png in any of your assets/images folder???

Comment: @akarsh using rails 4.0.2...I am not sure what the URL should be, I just want the image to be at the URL.

here is my views/pins/show.html.erb

<%= image_tag pin.image.url(:medium) %>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= pin.description %>
</p>

<% if pin.user == current_user%>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>

Comment: @aluxzi what exactly am I looking for in there?

Comment: @ghostRider user model posted above

Comment: @bjhaid my asset folder is empty

Comment: @Brunnals you said it does not give an error, there might be one in the development log.

Comment: @Brunnals if asset folder is empty then where would rails get the image from???

Comment: @Aluxzi here is the error that came up in the log:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"):

and then it says it rendered the routing error:
Rendered /Users/brianrunnals/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (26.7ms)

Comment: @bjhaid I am trying to upload the image and thats when this is happening. it seems to be placing /images/medium/missing.png on every image instead of saving it to my db

Comment: @Brunnals Try changing `config.serve_static_assets = false` to `true` in the `config/environments/production.rb` file.

Comment: @aluxzi no go... still scratching my head on this one

Answer (score 2):

GOT IT!!!! 
In app / views / pins / _form.html.erb update f.file_field to:

```
 <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
```